# Qt QML disable VSYNC buffer swap Scene3D

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have a Windows QML application with an embedded Scene3d object.

Whenever the Scene3d object is visible, the GPU usage climbs up to around 35% on a laptop with nothing on the scene.

I have set the `renderPolicy` to `RenderSettings.OnDemand` which shows a reduced framerate in the 3d diagnostics popup.

However...

If I set the logging rules to `qt.scenegraph.*=true;Qt3D.*=true` I get debug info spewing out at 60hz:

```
qt.scenegraph.renderloop: - polish and sync update request
qt.scenegraph.renderloop: polishAndSync (normal) QQuickView(0x6b6b9f6d8 exposed, visibility=QWindow::Windowed, flags=QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Window|CustomizeWindowHint), title="Log Viewer", geometry=386,150 1275x741)
2
qt.scenegraph.renderloop: update from item QQuickView(0x6b6b9f6d8 exposed, visibility=QWindow::Windowed, flags=QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Window|CustomizeWindowHint), title="Log Viewer", geometry=386,150 1275x741)
Qt3D.Core.Aspects: Processing Frame
Qt3D.Renderer.VsyncAdvanceService: Elapsed nsecs since last call  5888500
qt.scenegraph.renderloop: - lock for sync
qt.scenegraph.renderloop: - wait for sync
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) WM_RequestSync
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) --- done processEventsAndWaitForMore()
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) syncAndRender()
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) - updatePending, doing sync
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) sync()
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) sceneGraphChanged
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) - sync complete, waking Gui
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) - rendering started
qt.scenegraph.renderloop: - unlock after sync
qt.scenegraph.time.renderloop: Frame prepared with 'threaded' renderloop, polish=0, lock=1, blockedForSync=0, animations=0 - (on Gui thread) QQuickView(0x6b6b9f6d8 exposed, visibility=QWindow::Windowed, flags=QFlags<Qt::WindowType>(Window|CustomizeWindowHint), title="Log Viewer", geometry=386,150 1275x741)
qt.scenegraph.time.renderer: time in renderer: total=0ms, preprocess=0, updates=0, binding=0, rendering=0
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) - rendering done
qt.scenegraph.time.renderloop: Frame rendered with 'threaded' renderloop in 0ms, sync=0, render=0, swap=0 - (on render thread)
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) --- begin processEvents()
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) --- done processEvents()
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) done drawing, sleep...
qt.scenegraph.renderloop:                     (RT) --- begin processEventsAndWaitForMore()
```

I used the debugger to investigate what is happening, and the swap buffers function is getting called at the VSYNC frequency.

It would be good if swap buffers was only called on demand as per: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qrendersettings.html#RenderPolicy-enum

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? It might be worth trying a newer one. I remember they had a lot of performance issues in early (still in Qt 5.10) versions. In my [C++ based project](https://github.com/florianblume/6d-pat) I have a CPU usage as low as 5% with multiple 3D objects on my laptop.

Comment: Currently using 5.15.2

Comment: Ok then that's not the issue... The function `sceneGraphChanged` call in your stacktrace makes it look like it received a `sceneChanged` signal. The only suggestion I have right now is to download Qt sources and step through them to see what is happening. But looks like it's a Qt bug.